# How to change a background color in the NetBeans completion popup window?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have a black background of the code editor but a popup window with code completion has a white color with highlighted text.
[image]

How to change a background color or disable the highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the colors of the pop-up code completion and Javadoc windows are not directly configurable from within Netbeans.

It appears that the only way to accomplish this is to change the color scheme of your operating system's desktop to have black-backgrounded windows. (That means, of course, that all of your apps will have a black background.) This was tested and confirmed in Netbeans 7.3 development build 201212140001. Using Netbeans 7.2.1 there were some issues with this. Notably that the black background was present, but the text of the code completion and Javadoc windows were too dark. This was reported as part of and fixed in [Bug 134281](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=134281) for 7.3.

I would suggest that if you would like the code completion and Javadoc pop-up windows to match the editor color theme without having to change the OS color theme, that you see if someone has already submitted a similar request on Netbeans's "[Issues = Bugs, Feature Requests, and Enhancements](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html)" page. If so, vote for it. If not, submit one yourself. Be sure to differentiate it from #134281 which dealt with accessibility and OS color themes.

Comment: I am using netbeans 7.4 and I ma having the same problem. If this has been fixed do you know where do I go to fix this? Thanks Note: I am using netbeans for c not java (but I think the fix will be the same)